# Dorm / Hostel: How to assert myself politely with roommates

Tags: hostels, communication

I occasionally travel with agencies that will put me in a dorm room with one or two twenty-something year young students for three weeks straight. Though day program is tough, some of them like to party late, sometimes even in the dorm.

Therefore I'd like to ask, how I could politely communicate my needs like

- No smoking in our dorm room.
- Try to be silent and keep lights low in our dorm room after 11pm.
- Don't use my stuff without asking - and if I answered no, don't ignore that.
- Ask before the fact when you need the room for yourself and don't just lock me out, etc.

I'm looking for ways to do this right at day one, as well as just before / while / after an unexpected negative encounter.

Note: I usually offer more money to get my own room, but sometimes it's unavoidable. Hotels are usually not in the vicinity, hence not quite an alternative.

Comment: If you are an older person, then there is no way to avoid this. For 20 years old boys this is their normal lives, you can't change that fact.

Comment: Chill out and go with the flow if you don't want to change agencies. A lot of hostels (depending on country, location, chain, etc) are better for having fun than for resting.) Lock your stuff up and make some friends in other rooms in case you don't get along with your roommates. You can hang out or sleep in the common room / TV room if need be. Be flexible or you'll get more grumpy and tired. It helps if your itinerary isn't too crammed. Or so crammed that you'll be exhausted enough to sleep through anything.

Comment: As for locking out, in hostel you should become your own key, so it should be no-go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some tips I've gathered from staying in a lot of dorms:

If it's possible, try and get a bottom bunk and put a sheet/towel up, creating a "tent", so that if someone does turn the light on you aren't as disturbed.

Lock your stuff - if lockers aren't available, store everything on your bed during the day.

I'm not sure which countries you are staying in, but I would have thought that that smoking inside wouldn't be an option. If it is a problem, discuss with the check-in desk to see if you can change to a non-smoking room.

Your best bet is to introduce yourself during day hours, be nice and cheerful, explain that you're working etc and that you appreciate they're on their holidays but if they could be quiet you'd be really happy. If you come across happy and carefree rather than grumpy and dominant then you'll have a good time.